# String and number in for each

Tags: php, string, variables, numbers

I have this code:

```
$Awaarde = 8800;
$Bwaarde = 5500;

$arrayFondsen = array("A", "B");
foreach ($arrayFondsen as $letter)
{
    $data .= ${$letter."vroeger"} . " = " . number_format(((round(${$letter."waarde"}, -2))/1000), 1) . ";\n";
}
```

**Expected result** (to put as text in another PHP file):
$Avroeger = 8.8;
$Bvroeger = 5.5;

**Actual result:** (where the 8.3 and 5.7 are the old values of $Avroeger and $Bvroeger)
8.3 = 8.8;
5.7 = 5.5;

Anyone who can help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `${$letter."vroeger"} . " = "` should not be a variable variable. It should just be `$letter."vroeger" . " = "`

Comment: Why are you doing this? Variable variables are a horrible idea, use an associative array.

Comment: Actually I think the OP is trying to do something like `$data .= '$' . $letter . "vroeger" . " = " . `. Which of course would be better implemented as `$data .= sprintf("$%s%s = %d;\n", ...)`. Which of course is a horrible idea...

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar. I have made it a little different:
$data .= "$" . $letter."vroeger" . " = "
Works perfect now. Maybe it isn't the best PHP script, but I'm not a real programmer. I have never heard about associative arrays. Thanks again.

Comment: You should learn about them right now. No real PHP programmer uses variable variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the appending wrong. Do it as shown below.

```
$Awaarde = 8800;
$Bwaarde = 5500;
$data = '';
$arrayFondsen = array("A", "B");
foreach ($arrayFondsen as $letter)
{
    $data .= "$"."{$letter}vroeger = " . number_format(((round(${$letter."waarde"}, -2))/1000), 1) . ";\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/ikFWn1Zk1folfoc0)

Comment: That is even better and what a perfect site that you use for your demo. Thank you very much!!